# Multiple Task.Factory's

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library

I'm really loving the TPL. Simply calling `Task.Factory.StartNew()` and not worrying about anything, is quite amazing.

But, is it possible to have multiple Factories running on the same thread?
Basically, I have would like to have two different queues, executing different types of tasks.
One queue handles tasks of type A while the second queue handles tasks of type B.

If queue A has nothing to do, it should ignore tasks in queue B and vice versa.

Is this possible to do, without making my own queues, or running multiple threads for the factories?

To clarify what I want to do.

I read data from a network device. I want to do two things with this data, totally independent from each other.

1. I want to log to a database.
2. I want to send to another device over network.

Sometimes the database log will take a while, and I don't want the network send to be delayed because of this.

Comment: [StartNew is Dangerous](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/08/startnew-is-dangerous.html)

Comment: You are going to need a custom scheduler. A `Factory` simply builds the `Task` - a scheduler actually queues it. What are you trying to achieve. Perhaps there is more straight forward way of achieving it.

Comment: @SriramSakthivel `Task.Run` does not exist prior to .net 4.5...

Comment: @Gusdor Fine, You can specify all necessary parameters mainly the scheduler, or create your own factory with parameters defined once! That's not too hard

Comment: The power of TPL isn't in threads. The most powerful aspect come from pure callback I/O. Unless you really are CPU bound, stick to using `Task.Factory.FromAsync`

Comment: @Aron that really only works if you have an Asynchronous Programming Model pattern entry point defined - replaces this pattern.

Comment: Are you sure this is actually going to be a problem for you? Even if a single database log takes too long, the network work will most likely execute at the same time on another thread.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use .NET 4.0:

- `LimitedConcurrencyLevelTaskScheduler` (with concurrency level of 1; see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee789351))

If you use .NET 4.5:

- `ConcurrentExclusiveSchedulerPair` (take only the exclusive scheduler out of the pair; see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12068645/how-do-i-create-a-scheduler-which-never-executes-more-than-one-task-at-a-time-us))

Create two schedulers and pass them to the appropriate `StartNew`. Or create two `TaskFactories` with these schdulers and use them to create and start the tasks.

Answer (score 0):

You can define yourself a thread pool using a queue of threads